# Tell Swing to recalculate JMenu width when I change text contents of JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing

I've been a little lazy and instead of making another window, I created single menu for my update manager. I plan on making the window, but there are more important tasks to attend, so this must just do for now:

[image: image description]

Clicking on that last menu item dynamically changes the text when there's an update. If the user is viewing the menu item at that moment, the size of the `JMenu` doesn't change:

[image: image description]

If I move mouse away and navigate back to the menu, the size is correct:

[image: image description]

I need to tell Swing to update size of the `JMenuItem` when I change the text. I have a class called [`UpdateMenuItem`](https://github.com/Darker/auto-client/blob/develop/src/cz/autoclient/GUI/updates/UpdateMenuItem.java) which extends the `JMenuItem` with functions like this:

```
  public void setDownloadAvailable(final VersionId version) {
    // Checking if the code runs in correct thread
    // this should probably also raise a warning if not in the swing thread
    if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->setDownloadAvailable(version));
      return;
    }
    // this is how the menu text changes
    setText("Click to download: "+version);
    setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
  }
```

I need to add appropriate code after the `setText` call to have the size of the item correctly updated. What method should I call?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMenu#getPopupMenu()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getPopupMenu--) and [JPopupMenu#pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#pack--) works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JMenuItemPackTest {
  public JMenuBar makeMenuBar() {
    JMenuItem label = new JMenuItem("Up to date: 3.5-beta");
    label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
//     UpdateMenuItem label = new UpdateMenuItem("Up to date: 3.5-beta") {
//       @Override public void setDownloadAvailable(final VersionId version) {
//         super.setDownloadAvailable(version);
//         Container c = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(this);
//         if (c instanceof JPopupMenu) {
//           ((JPopupMenu) c).pack();
//         }
//       }
//     };

    JMenu update = new JMenu("Updates");
    update.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Auto-check for updates"));
    update.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Auto-download"));
    update.add(label);

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Help");
    menu.add(update);

    (new Timer(5000, e -> {
      //...
      label.setText("Click to download: 3.5-beta");
      label.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
      update.getPopupMenu().pack();
      //or:
      //Container c = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(label);
      //if (c instanceof JPopupMenu) {
      //  ((JPopupMenu) c).pack();
      //}
    })).start();

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    menubar.add(menu);
    return menubar;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setJMenuBar(new JMenuItemPackTest().makeMenuBar());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I tested it and it works, so if any visitor is having problems this answer is correct.